# Date Strings to be used for a range of dates

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with this function where basically I am selecting two dates from two different calendars, printing those said dates in textboxes, and then I want to gain access (like it's done in the commented lines) to some information that's stored in a JSON separately. I am trying to get every CountyInfectionNumber and every Incidence from each day between the chosenDate_start and chosenDate_end.

As you can see the format is kinda wonky, but that's the way it's written in my JSON file.

My problem resides within these two lines:

```
DateTime loadedDate_start = DateTime.ParseExact(chosenDate_start, "d", null);
DateTime loadedDate_end = DateTime.ParseExact(chosenDate_end, "d", null);
```

What am I doing wrong? It says that chosenDate_ cannot be a string, but isn't that what ParseExact is supposed to be doing?

@insane_developer solved this one in the comments, props to him

```
        {
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                json = webClient.DownloadString("https://datelazi.ro/latestData.json");
            }
            var semiParsedData = JObject.Parse(json);

            string chosenDate_start;
            string chosenDate_end;
            string chosenCounty;

            ZiAleasaatunci.Text = Calendar_de_Ales_Inc.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            ZiSfarsitAleasaAtunci.Text = Calendar_Ales_Sf.SelectionRange.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            chosenDate_start = ZiAleasaatunci.Text;
            chosenDate_end = ZiSfarsitAleasaAtunci.Text;
            chosenCounty = JudeteAtunci.Text;

            
            //var countySpecificInfections = semiParsedData.SelectToken($"historicalData.{chosenDate_start}.countyInfectionsNumbers.{chosenCounty}");
            //var countySpecificIncidence = semiParsedData.SelectToken($"historicalData.{chosenDate_start}.incidence.{chosenCounty}");
           
            //NumarCazuriAtunci.Text = countySpecificInfections.Value<int>().ToString();
            //IncidentaAtunci.Text = countySpecificIncidence.Value<double>().ToString();
            

            DateTime loadedDate_start = DateTime.ParseExact(chosenDate_start, "d", null);
            DateTime loadedDate_end = DateTime.ParseExact(chosenDate_end, "d", null);

            List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();

            

            DateTime Zi_Aleasa = loadedDate_start ;
            DateTime Zi_Precedenta = Zi_Aleasa.AddDays(-1);
            Console.WriteLine(Zi_Precedenta);

             
            for (DateTime date = loadedDate_start; date <= loadedDate_end; date = date.AddDays(1))
                allDates.Add(date);
  
           


        }
```

Comment: Can you give the exact value chosenDate_start is for you, and the exact error message you get?

Comment: chosenDate_start is whatever the user selects from the calendar, so is chosedDate_end. They are in yyyy-MM-dd format so one example could be 2021-01-19 (today). The exact error message that I get is this: System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' at those two lines I mentioned above

Comment: `"MM/dd/yyyy"` is the pattern associated with the short date format specifier (`"d"`). So `"2021-01-19"` does not seem valid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#ShortDate

Comment: If you add the format in the call, it should work fine: `DateTime loadedDate_start = DateTime.ParseExact(chosenDate_start, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);`

Comment: yes, that worked out perfectly, I thought that "d" would just be a placeholder and that it will auto recognize the format. Thank you very much!